# Webpack source-map targets to *.min.js bundle and not to the source files in production mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-4, source-maps

we have almost the same configuration for development and production mode in webpack. In both cases we want to have source maps to be able to debug in browser. For development mode all works fine. Our source files appear in the browser dev tools and all our files are listed in the app2.min.js.map file.

```
{
    "version":3,
    "sources":[
        "webpack:///webpack/bootstrap",
        "webpack:///./app2/app.dev.ts",
        "webpack:///./app2/app.module.ts",
        "webpack:///./app2/app.routing.ts",
        "webpack:///./app2/components/absenceManagement/...
        ...
```

But in production mode the source map targets back to the minified bundle file

```
{
    "version":3,
    "sources":[
        "webpack:///js/app2.min.js"
    ],
    "names":[
        "modules","installedModules",
        "__webpack_require__",
        ...
```

Therefore the bundled js file targets to the source map (`//# sourceMappingURL=app2.min.js.map`) and the source map back to the bundle file.

Our configuration
webpack.dev.js

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = function () {
    return webpackMerge(commonConfig,
        {
            devtool: 'source-map',

            entry: {
                app: './app2/app.dev.ts'
            },
            mode: 'development'
        });
}
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = function () {
    return webpackMerge(commonConfig,
        {
            devtool: 'source-map',

            entry: {
                app: './app2/app.prod.ts'
            },
            mode: 'production'
        });
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');

module.exports = {

    // Currently we need to add '.ts' to the resolve.extensions array.
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.html', '.css'],
        modules: ['app2', 'node_modules', 'js']
    },

    // Add the loader for .ts files.
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /\.spec\.ts$/,
                use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CheckerPlugin()
    ],
    stats: {
        colors: false
    },
    output: {
        filename: './js/app2.min.js'
    }
};
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./@types/",
      "./node_modules/@types/",
      "./js/"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "typemoq": [ "js/typemoq" ]
    },
    "types": [
      "lodash",
      "moment",
      "jquery",
      "typemoq"
    ]
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
        "useCache": true
    },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

some of the package.json

```
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    ...
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.1.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Setup `terser-webpack-plugin` in your webpack config. Therefore see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/
2. And then use `UglifyJS` for the minification of your code. See: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#terseroptions and https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#minify-options.
3. Also disable the optimiztion that is done by webpack itself which you can do with:

```
    module.exports = {
      //...
       optimization: {
       minimize: false,
      },
    };`
```

Your configuration for your productive environment should look like this:

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function () {
    return webpackMerge(commonConfig,
        {
            devtool: 'source-map',

            entry: {
                app: './app2/app.prod.ts'
            },
            mode: 'production',
            optimization: {
                minimizer: [
                    new TerserPlugin({
                        parallel: true,
                        minify: TerserPlugin.uglifyJsMinify,
                        terserOptions: {
                            sourceMap: {
                                filename: 'app2.min.js',
                                url: 'app2.min.js.map'
                            }
                        },
                   }),
                ],
             },
        });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does change nothing. I get the same result in the source-map.